# Smart String Replacements

Tags: javascript

This works well for case insensitive replacements:

```
str = str.replace(new RegExp(phrase, 'gi'), '<span style="color:red;">' + phrase + '</span>');
```

But what I do want is to not change case when replaced which above-mentioned does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str = str.replace(new RegExp(phrase, 'gi'), '<span>$&</span>');`

Comment: This one works! Thanks! The one reko_t suggested does not work at least in my Opera.

Answer (score 0):

Capture the phrase with parenthesis, and use `$1` in the replace string, eg:

```
'Foobar'.replace(/(foo)/gi, '<x>$1</x>')
```

Would result in `<x>Foo</x>bar`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. There is a capturing group, and `$1` refers to the first captured group.

Comment: Ah oops, it seems like I forgot to add parenthesis around foo, and Kobi added them for me. Sorry about that!